# Chamar um método dentro de um método em Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, orientação-a-objetos, funções

Segue a classe:

```
class Advogado{
        constructor(nomeAdv, tipoEnderecoAdv, ruaAdv, numAvd, cidadeAdv, estadoAdv, oabADV, estadoOabAdv, emailAdv){
          this.nomeAdv = nomeAdv;
          this.tipoEndereco = tipoEnderecoAdv;
          this.ruaAdv = ruaAdv;
          this.numAvd = numAvd;
          this.cidadeAdv = cidadeAdv;
          this.estadoAdv = estadoAdv;
          this.oabADV = oabADV;
          this.estadoOabAdv = estadoOabAdv;
          this.emailAdv = emailAdv;


        }
         geraEnderecoAdv(){
           return `${this.tipoEnderecoAdv} ${this.ruaAdv}, nº ${this.numAvd}, na cidade de ${this.cidadeAdv} - ${this.estadoAdv}`;
         }

         dizOutorgado (){
           return `${this.nomeAdv}, brasileiro(a), inscrito(a) na OAB/${this.estadoOabAdv} nº ${this.oabADV}, com escritório na ${this.tipoEndereco} ${geraenderecoAdv()} e email ${this.emailAdv}, onde recebe intimações`;
         }

      }
```

Como faço para o método dizOutorgado(), que chama o geraEnderecoAdv() funcionar? Ele sempre diz que o método chamado é inexistente.

Mais uma coisa. Se eu transformar o objeto criado nessa classe em um Json com JSON.stringify e depois o recuperar perderei os métodos mantendo apenas os pares chave/valor?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo código que você colocou, está **geraenderecoAdv()** e não **geraEnderecoAdv()**. Depois você terá que colocar o **this** na chamada do método. Veja se funciona. Caso não funcione, tente mudar os métodos para arrow functions.

Comment: Mano, como eu sou burro... Eu sentia que era algo básico. Nem precisou usar as arrow functions... Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Só para deixar registrado um exemplo no site, você precisa usar o **this** para referenciar o método e também concatenar aos outros textos.

```js
class Advogado {
  constructor(nomeAdv, tipoEnderecoAdv, ruaAdv, numAvd, cidadeAdv, estadoAdv, oabADV, estadoOabAdv, emailAdv) {
    this.nomeAdv = nomeAdv;
    this.tipoEnderecoAdv = tipoEnderecoAdv;
    this.ruaAdv = ruaAdv;
    this.numAvd = numAvd;
    this.cidadeAdv = cidadeAdv;
    this.estadoAdv = estadoAdv;
    this.oabADV = oabADV;
    this.estadoOabAdv = estadoOabAdv;
    this.emailAdv = emailAdv;


  }
  geraEnderecoAdv() {
    return `${this.tipoEnderecoAdv} ${this.ruaAdv}, nº ${this.numAvd}, na cidade de ${this.cidadeAdv} - ${this.estadoAdv}`;
  }

  dizOutorgado() {
    return `${this.nomeAdv}, brasileiro(a), inscrito(a) na OAB/${this.estadoOabAdv} nº ${this.oabADV}, com escritório na `+  this.geraEnderecoAdv()+ ` e email ${this.emailAdv}, onde recebe intimações`;
  }

}

let Adv = new Advogado('Marcelo Flemmingham', 'Avenida', 'Roberto Frizzo', 404, 'São Paulo', 'SP', 1231212121, 'RJ', 'marcelo@teste.com')

document.write(Adv.dizOutorgado());
```

Agora quanto a sua segunda pergunta, não ficou claro, pq quando instancia a classe, isto vai gerar um **objeto**, com os atributos da classe mais os dados preenchidos na instanciação da classe, se você der um **`console.log(JSON.stringify(Adv))`** apenas vai transformar aquela instancia da classe de objeto para **string**, mas, a classe continua com os métodos dela normal, acho que você fez algum tipo de confusão aí.